# rails SQL query reported failing with postgres but succeeds from psql command-line tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to use a Rails 2.3.5 app with Postgres9.1 on Ubuntu (deployed on Apache2 with Phusion Passenger). The app throws this error when I try to access it, complaining that table does not exist:

```
PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                    ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum
```

However if I cut and paste the same query at the psql (cmdline-client), it works just fine.
The users table exists too. I tried a rake db:reset and 'rake db:migrate' again and again but it doesn't seem to help.
I also verified that the ActiveRecord::Base.connection succeeds from the script/console in the rails-appwhich means the connection to the database works with the credentials configured in database.yml.

I am lost.. any clues to remedy this will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: My bet is, that you are connecting to a different DB from within Rails

Comment: Thanks much for your response, Edwin and "a_horse..". T'was connection to wrong DB.  I'd configured the app for development mode (via environment.rb). But my setting was being overridden by Phusion Passenger (which I was using with apache); it sets the RailsEnv to 'production' by default. Since I'd earlier used 'rake db:create:all', the prod DB did get created but my 'rake db:migrate' only populated the development DB.  I had to change the apache site configuration to set RailsEnv development as shown here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env.

Comment: @Don: a_horse_with_no_name had his money on the right horse. Cool that it works. I *do* wonder about this mysterious *Edwin* guy, though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possible causes.

1) The [special cast ::regclass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) takes the current setting for [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-client.html) into account.
Maybe your table `users` is in a schema that is not in the `search_path` when querying from your app. `search_path` can be set per user or session.
Solution would be to schema-qualify the table-name like this:

```
'myschema.users'::regclass
```

2) Capitalization. Why `'"users"'::regclass` and not `'users'::regclass`? This is redundant. Is the actual name of the Table "Users" or something and you use upper case in psql? (If you actually cut & paste the query, this can't be it.)

3) Connection to the wrong database. Wrong port? (See comment by @a_horse.)

Comment: Thanks much for your response, Edwin and "a_horse..". T'was connection to wrong DB.  I'd configured the app for development mode (via environment.rb). But my setting was being overridden by Phusion Passenger (which I was using with apache); it sets the RailsEnv to 'production' by default. Since I'd earlier used 'rake db:create:all', the prod DB did get created but my 'rake db:migrate' only populated the development DB.  I had to change the apache site configuration to set RailsEnv development as shown here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#rails_env.